# AND statement in mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to run a query in **MySQL** database with **C#**. I want the column **prioritySettings** returned when the 3 previous columns are within certain values. This query works, but only with one variable at a time, so at the moment I can only specify the value of one of the columns. Are my `AND` statements correct?

```
string query = "SELECT prioritySetting FROM {DATABASE} WHERE handling ='" + handling + "'" + "AND corner ='" + corner + "'" + "AND power  ='" + power + "'";
```

some more code;

```
                 MySqlDataReader sqlReader;                                       
                string handling = overOrUnderInput;
                string corner = cornerPartInput;
                string power = onOrOffPowerInput;
                string query = "SELECT prioritySetting FROM {DATABASE} WHERE handling ='" +             handling + "'" + " AND corner ='" + corner + "'" + " AND power  ='" + power + "'"; 
                MySqlCommand getRecords = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                sqlReader = getRecords.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {

                        try
                        {

                            try
                            {

                                suggestions[i] = (sqlReader.GetString(0));
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }
                            i++;

                        }
                        catch (MySqlException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
```

and the error;

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference was not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Do you mean TABLE instead of DATABASE Right?

Comment: you need a space in front of AND

Comment: Space is missing before the AND

Comment: add a space before and

Comment: What is the error received if any?

Comment: thanks, i used {database} to represent my database, i do actaully have the database.Table in my code

Comment: the error is that i have an array that gets data out of the database and there is a null exception

Comment: I suggest to post the whole code around this call and the exact error message because this  should not fail unless one of your input contains a single quote. I am pretty sure that the error is not here

Comment: Please read this [What is a null reference exception and how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ok thank you very much. Ill report back, that link should help!

Answer (score 4):

Seem like a space is required before each `AND`.

Comment: I would suggest to test this answer against a real query

Comment: thanks, i tried this but i am still getting the same error, a null exception is thrown when it tries to save data into an array

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before each `AND`

```
string query = "SELECT prioritySetting FROM {DATABASE} WHERE handling ='" + handling + "'" + " AND corner ='" + corner + "'" + " AND power  ='" + power + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how your query looks if the parameters are inserted. I assume parameters have values equal to their names.

```
SELECT prioritySetting 
FROM {DATABASE} 
WHERE handling ='handling'AND corner ='corner'AND power  ='power'
```

If it's really `DATABASE` after the `FROM` you should change it to `TABLE`. I'm not very sure if it causes any problems, but I strongly recommend putting spaces before `AND`s. So your code line will be like:

```
string query = "SELECT prioritySetting FROM {DATABASE.TABLE} WHERE handling ='" + handling + "'" + " AND corner ='" + corner + "'" + " AND power  ='" + power + "'";
```

Comment: tried inserting them "manually" and i got the same error (null exception when tried to save into array) as when they were being inserted by a variable

Comment: can you please provide your table schema and some more code. (especially where it throws the error)

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT prioritySetting FROM {TABLE}
                    WHERE handling ='" + handling + "'" + " 
                    AND corner ='" + corner + "'" + "
                    AND power  ='" + power + "'";
```